# Logo will not overlap on top of background image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the logo to overlap the background image (see screenshot below) div with

```
position: absolute;
```

for the .header div and

```
position: relative;
```

for the .logo-svrs div

It seems that the external div will not overlap the .bg-banner. The overflow: visible didn't work either. No success.

I had to show the header of the logo by putting the

```
display: visible;
```

to be able to see the location of the logo. On the screenshot below, the right screenshot is what I need.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="http://www.svrs.com"><img src="imgs/logo-svrs.png" class="logo-svrs" alt="Sorenson VRS"></a>
</div>
<div class="bg-banner">
    <div class="notice-wrapper">
        <div class="notice-overlay">
            <div class="notices effect">
                <div class="box-left-bad">
                    <img src="imgs/exclamatory.png" alt="Warning! - Sorenson VRS">
                    <p class="good">WARNING!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-right-bad">
                    <p>We are currently experiencing a technical difficulty that may be impacting our service.  You may want to try restarting your device (VP, VP2, PC, Mac or mobile device) to see if this resolves the issue.  At this time, we do not know when the technical difficulty will be resolved.  We are working to quickly resolve the problem.  This message will no longer appear on this page when the issue is resolved.</p> 
                    <p>Thank you for your patience.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width:732px) and (min-width:425px) {
.logo-svrs {
    position: relative !important;
    display: block !important;
    width: 114px;
    height: 29.5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: solid #ff0000 3px !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
 }
.header {  
    display: visible;
}
.bg-banner {
    position: absolute !important;
    background-image: url(../imgs/apply_header.jpg) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 40% !important; 
    z-index: 0;
}
.notices {
    position: relative !important;
    width: 370px !important;
    height: 350px !important;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 200px !important;
    z-index: 9999;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    box-shadow:  0 0 10px  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
}
```

[image: logo to overlap background image]

Comment: Did you try adding `position:absolute` to the LOGO image? Then you can just use `top: x px;`

Comment: There's no positioning information such as pixels from the left, right, top or bottom on the `position:absolute;` elememt

Comment: @Ellisan - that worked, but the problem is the how do I get rid of .header that leaves a white background on the top. I put display: none; the logo disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the .header div inside the `.bg-banner` div and add this

**css:**

```
.header {  
    display: visible; /*this is not valid*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Here is a possible solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/kd91t26L/3/

Comment: Yep, that worked, but the problem is the how do I get rid of .header that leaves a white background on the top. That needs to go away.

Comment: it should not leave a white background, if you set the .header div to position: absolute; could you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/u6vfzwzg/1/ - the logo alt disappeared using your codes. When the logo is in the background image the white background of the header should go away. Can it be transparent?

Comment: This is what Im showing right now with your codes - http://staging.vrsii.com/beacon/imgs/logo-issue.jpg - I need to get rid of the white background. Can it be done in transparently?

Comment: I figured and put background-color: transparent !important; and that got rid of the header background - thank you so much!